# synapseRT integration with Pace Automation Framework

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

Does PAF supports **synapseRT** integration of automation scripts? 
synapseRT is a Requirements & Test management system in Jira. 
If yes, Please provide a brief introduction to establish the integration.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** . PAF supports integration with synapseRT.

- Following properties needs to be configured to connect synapseRT through PAF.
  TEST_SYSTEM=srt 
  HOST= 
  PROJECT= 
  PASSWORD=(base64 encrypted value of username:password) 
  PWD_ENCRYPTED=false 
  TEST_FOLDER_ID= 
  REMOVE_XML_FROM_STEP=false 
  TEST_SET_NAME= 
  CYCLE_NAME=
- To encrypt the password to base64 encryption following website can be used. 
  https://www.base64encode.net/